# How often the WSDL URL should be read?

Tags: web-services, wsdl

Just once to get the address location and use it forever?

Every time a call is made?

Or some time in between?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The only purpose of the WSDL URL is to return the WSDL that describes the current service.
- The only reason to ever read it is if the reader does not have the WSDL that describes the current service.
- The only time a reader would need to read it is if they never had the WSDL that described the service, or if the service has changed.

Some downlevel clients are pretty stupid and need to download the WSDL before each call. Avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you are trying to do.  If you're calling or referencing the Web Service...you will need to re-reference it when the Web Service interface changes.  If the Web Service interface won't change,  then you only need to reference it once

Answer (score 1):

I agree with John and would add that in most cases you don't need the WSDL to be hosted on a URL at all. Unless you have a public web service that anyone can sign up and use you're probably better off to keep the wsdl to yourself and only fork it out to specific users as needed.